# Load Testing of a web page or mySQL database

Tags: mysql, testing, load

I have a page, and at a time 1000 of entries to this form has to be made. For Ex: a scenario like the following- number of users accessing or entering data into a single web page from different locations.
so this scenario has to be generated to test the load. Manually entering is tedious, so is there any tool for entering such datas.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some tools for this in wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing#Software_load_testing

I know some people using JMeter for this with success.

Comment: I've also used JMeter for this sort of thing, but not recently.  It was relatively easy to get hold of and get setup, and to script different scenarios.